# Colouring in a JPanel using mouseClicked - Error

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, coordinate

Good day,

I might've been a bit vague with the title of my question, but I hope this will explain. The scenario is quite basic - I have a JFrame, in which I have an array of JPlanes. The idea is that when I click on one of them, upon clicking in should become black. Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class PixelArt {

    JFrame frame;
    Border blackline;
    JPanel squares[][] = new JPanel[100][100];
    int x;
    int y;

    public PixelArt() {

        frame = new JFrame("Pixel Art");
        frame.setSize(1000, 1000);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(100, 100));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
                x = i;
                y = j;
                squares[i][j] = new JPanel();
                squares[i][j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createDashedBorder(null));
                squares[i][j].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

                        x = e.getX();
                        y = e.getY();
                        squares[x][y].setBackground(Color.black); 

                    }
                });

                frame.add(squares[i][j]);
            }
        }

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PixelArt();
    }
}
```

The actual problem is that this code does not do what I explained above. It does color in one of the JPlane's black when clicked, but within a *9x9 area starting from the upper corner of the grid*. I do not have an explanation for this. The problem seems to be in the following 2 lines:

```
    x = e.getX();
    y = e.getY();
```

One of my guesses is that I have some kind of an offset in the coordinate system, but then this does not explain why regardless on which JPanel I press, the JPanels colored are only in the upper 9x9 area.

Does anyone have a clue how I could fix the problem I described above? If something is unclear in my explanation, please ask. Thank you in advance.

Here is a screenshot of the working code:

[image: Screenshot of working code]

Comment: `Mouse#getX` and `Mouse#getY` return the pixel position of the mouse event relative to the component which generated the event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can detect clicked panel using `event.getSource()` like follow example code

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        JPanel panel = (JPanel)e.getSource();// 
        panel.setBackground(Color.black); 

}
```

the problem is you can't use `x`,`y` directly as indexes to array element. because panels has a width and borders too.if you go with x y you have to make some mathematics logic. for example you click middle of your first jpanel in the grid so let's assume x and y coordinate is about 10px but in your code you call `[10][10]` Janel but actually you should call `[0][0]`.
also as @Cr0w3 says you add listners to all panels.so if you clicked middle of first grid cell or last grid cell there is no difference in x,y.

but if you make a mathematical logic to detect clicked element you need to take in to account your frame/main panel width(also have to update when risize) and border thickness.

also do you really want to do this using **10000 panels ?** you may need use a one panel and override paint component method.10000 panels isn't effective for this kind of thing.if you resize or click quickly on panels you will see it take a lot of time. so you may need to draw graphics on a jpanel .see this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15870608/creating-a-draw-rectangle-filled-with-black-color-function-in-java-for-a-grid)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not add the listener to the panels themselves, but to the frame.

Because the X and Y coordinates might be relative to the panel size (e.g., upper corner of the panel returns 1/1, thus you apply the color to the panel at [1][1] even though you click the panel at [50][50].

If you use the frame for listening at the point you will receive 50/50 as coordinates.

Unfortunately I cannot comment, because of my low reputation but I hope I could help a little.

If you want to add a listener to the panel do not use the coordinates and just apply color to the clicked panel without listening to the coordinates. Using e.getSource() should help you in that case.