# Is there a way to repaint graphics after using super.paint(g)?

Tags: java, graphics

so I have a question, lets say I create a rectangle in Java using the paint method, after a 100 ms delay I do super.paint(g), this clears the rectangle previously shown, is there a way to make it re appear?

Thanks!

An example of what I'm talking about is down below, what this program is meant to do is whenever I hold down mouse button 1, it creates a rectangle that goes down and than disapears after mouse button 1 is off. The problem is whenever I hold down mouse button 1 again, the rectangle doesn't appear.

First class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class RecoilHelper extends JFrame {


static Timer rs;
static int recoil = 540;
static boolean clearRectangle = false;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JNativehookRecoilHelp.main(null);
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                RecoilHelper frame = new RecoilHelper();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public RecoilHelper() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    
    setBounds(0, 0, 1920, 1080);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setUndecorated(true);
    setBackground(new Color(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,0.0f));
    setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    
    rs = new Timer(10,(ActionEvent e)->{
        repaint();
        
        recoil += 12;
    
    
        if (recoil>600) {
            
            rs.stop();
        }
        
    });

    
}

public void paint(Graphics g) { 
     
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(960, recoil, 4, 4);
    System.out.println(recoil);
    super.paintComponents(g);
    g.fillRect(
       (int)r.getX(),
       (int)r.getY(),
       (int)r.getWidth(),
       (int)r.getHeight()
    );  
    if (clearRectangle) {
        super.paint(g);
    } 
    
}

}
```

Second class(tracks mouse button 1 events using JNativehook):

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.LogManager;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen;
import org.jnativehook.NativeHookException;
import org.jnativehook.mouse.NativeMouseEvent;
import org.jnativehook.mouse.NativeMouseInputListener;

public class JNativehookRecoilHelp implements NativeMouseInputListener {

@Override
public void nativeMouseClicked(NativeMouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void nativeMousePressed(NativeMouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Pressed");
    RecoilHelper.recoil = 540;
    RecoilHelper.rs.start();

}

@Override
public void nativeMouseReleased(NativeMouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Released");
    RecoilHelper.clearRectangle=true;
    
}

@Override
public void nativeMouseDragged(NativeMouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}

@Override
public void nativeMouseMoved(NativeMouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GlobalScreen.addNativeMouseListener(new JNativehookRecoilHelp());
    LogManager.getLogManager().reset();

    // Get the logger for "org.jnativehook" and set the level to off.
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GlobalScreen.class.getPackage().getName());
    logger.setLevel(Level.OFF);

    try {
        GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
    }
    catch (NativeHookException ex) {
        


        System.exit(1);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: You need to override the `paintComponent` method of the component. I strongly recommend completing this entire tutorial to learn how it works: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a draw rectangle (filled with black color) function in Java for a grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15870608/creating-a-draw-rectangle-filled-with-black-color-function-in-java-for-a-grid)

Comment: Hi @sorifiend, I'm not entirely sure if this is the answer to my question because when I tried to do something similar, it looks like it doesn't work (or I just did it completely wrong) I had updated my post about this, can you look over it? thanks!

Comment: You are required to call `super.paint` unless you're willing to take over all the duties it performs.  Instead, maybe try calling it first then paint your rectangle when `clearRectangle` is `false`.  Painting can occur for many different reasons, many which you don't control

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are attempting to override the paint method of the JFrame, this presents two issues, this first is that a JFrame is a heavyweight component (it has a title bar and a number of associated things that you need to consider) so you may have endless issues, the second issue is that you need to override the `paintComponent` method of the component that you wish to perform custom painting on.

The solution here is to instead place a JPanel inside the JFrame, and override the paintComponent method of the JPanel.

Below is a working example that creates a new rectangle and adds it to the frame every half second but also keeps the existing rectangles by adding them to a list and drawing each one in the list every time it is repainted.

The main class is simple, and simply adds our CustomJpanel to the JFrame:

```
public class PaintExample extends JFrame
{
    private CustomJPanel customJpanel;
    
    public PaintExample()
    {
        //Create and add the custom panel to the JFrame
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        customJpanel = new CustomJPanel();
        getContentPane().add(customJpanel, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        //Show the JFrame:
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new PaintExample().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And the custom panel class that does our painting:

```
public class CustomJPanel extends JPanel
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    boolean clearRectangle = true;
    //This is a list that we use to keep track of all the rectangles to draw/update
    ArrayList<Rectangle> rectangleList = new ArrayList<>();
    
    //Start a timer when the panel is created that will update the rectangle location every half second (500ms).
    //In your case you would use your recoil timer instead
    public CustomJPanel(){
        //Create event action
        ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                add a new rectangle in a different location
                x+= 5;
                y+= 5;
                rectangleList.add(new Rectangle(x,y,10,10));
                //Update the panel
                repaint();
            }
        };
        //Create and start a repeating event
        Timer timer = new Timer(500, taskPerformer);
        timer.setRepeats(true);
        timer.start();
    }
    
    //Here is where it all happens:
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        //Call super first to perform normal component painting
        super.paintComponent(g);
        //Now do your custom painting
        if (clearRectangle)
        {
            //Draw each rectangle in the list
            for (Iterator<Rectangle> iterator = rectangleList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
            {
                Rectangle r = iterator.next();
                g.drawRect(r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the window looks like this after a couple so seconds, note how it keeps all previous rectangles:
[image: Example output]